# Ionic - embedded videos not working on ios

Tags: ios, angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework, video-player

I have an ionic app where I am displaying videos and that works fine when I test it in chrome browser and on android device, but nothing gets displayed on iphone. This is my html code:

```
<iframe ng-show="article.external_media.length > 0 && article.external_media.url != ''" ng-src="{{article.external_media[0].url | safeUrl }} "></iframe>
```

Comment: I guess it could be your ios blocking any arbitrary request from external locations.

Comment: do you have any suggestions how to overcome that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am posting the solution I found to the problem if anyone will need it in the future.This is what finally got the iframes to work on ios:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem comes from ios blocking external requests, add a configuration line on you `.plist` file like so:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: I had that already, but when I added this line <allow-navigation href="*" /> to the config.xml it finally started working on ios.

Comment: It makes sense, you should update the answer or create a new one as the solution for this issue.

Comment: I agree, I have posted the answer. Thank you for your help!